# I see string "urlToImage" in json answer, but my gsonfactory not parsing it! Why?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

### SOLVED

I am doing async call using retrofit, and when I receive JSON response, viewing network log **I see** that it contains **"urlToImage"** string with some url, but when my gsonfactory parses it into json Model "urlToImage" is ALWAYS **null**.

I [generated](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) POJO object with JSON response I am receiving and used it as Json Model - hasn't worked out.

I tried to parse another strings from that response for test and every string is smooth, except strings "publishedAt" and "urlToImage". They are always null.

---

In JSON answer "urlToImage" is not null:

[image: answe]

---

My JSON Model:

```
public class Article {

    private Source source;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String urlToImage;

----< constructor, getters and setters >----

  private class Source {

        private String name;

----< constructor, getters and setters >----
  }
}
```

---

Breakpoint where I see full parsed json. Also I see that urlToImage is always null:

[image: null]

---

Example of JSON answer (published on site that provides API):

[image: example]

---

My response model:

```
public class JSONResponseArticles {
    private String status;
    private Article[] articles;

    public Article[] getArticles() {
        return articles;
    }
}
```

---

My GSON Factory [(github)](https://github.com/st4ycool/PocketNews2/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/pocketnews/di/NetModule.java#L38):

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGson() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        return gsonBuilder.create();
    }
```

---

### Update 1

As @MC_Emperor noticed, there was `FieldNamingPolicy` set to my gsonbuilder. Full:

`gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);`
So:

- I tried to rename urlToImage to url_to_image - no effect, still null;
- I tried to setup `FieldNamingPolicy.IDENITY` docs: "using
  this naming policy with Gson will ensure that the field name is
  unchanged." - no effect, still null.
- I removed FieldNamingPolicy - no effect.
- I removed GSON builder and now I just passing gsonfactory like 
  `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` when 
  creating retrofit object - no effect, still null.

---

Also I found this [thread](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1094) on Retrofit's github issues where developers calls this behavior "a bug" in septerber 2015. I dunno it's me, or what?

---

### Update 2

in my dependencies I had only `'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'`, but when I added `'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'` urlToImage appeared with value different from null! WOW.

Comment: Can we see the code where you call the Gson library? It could be the fact that the field names contain uppercase characters.

Comment: @MCEmperor added to the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you explicitly told Gson to do this.

```
gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
```

expects your field `urlToImage` to be mapped to a json key `url_to_image`.

You see that the properties of the JSON example are already written in camelCase. These are equal to the fields you defined in your model. If you remove the field naming policy, it'll work.

Comment: Yes! Because every other field is one word, so it's no underscores. I noticed this gson policy yesterday at night, and somehow it hasn't built successfuly, but now I SEE IT. Thank you so much )

Comment: Same happened to `publishedAt`, that's why I noticed :-)